# Autoscrolling of images and perform action on click images

Tags: ios, swift, autoscaling

I want to create autoscroll of images and want to perform action on click of image. [Same as iTune home page]. I really stuck to perform this task.
Please give me some suggestion or any reference how I can perform same.
Autoscroll is main thing for me as well images should scroll in infinite loop same as iTune Home Page . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **table view** for show each cell.
if you want to show images in each cell then use **collection view inside a table view cell.**

so it's look like a app store home page.

Comment: Pradeep Thanks for you response, But if user  will scroll in left side on first cell of collectionview then it can not be. But on app store it can be both side scroll in infinite loop.